# ImageVIew change source for a limited time on buttonClick

Tags: android, imageview

There is an ImageView and a button. When button gets clicked an imageview should change the source(display another image) for 1 second and then go back to default source which is defined in layout file.

How to do that???

Thanks in advance

Comment: please, do not offer a selector solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change image when button clicked

```
ImageView image;
image.setImageResource(R.drawable.newimage);
```

and after 2 second change default image

```
Handler handler = new Handler(); 
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
    public void run() {
        ImageView image;
        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.defaultimage);
    } 
}, 2000);
```

Comment: ImageButton barkk = (ImageButton) this.findViewById(R.id.barkk);  
  barkk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    playSound(bark); 
    
    
  
    ImageView dog = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.dog);
    dog.setImageResource(R.drawable.dog2);
    
    
    Handler handler = new Handler(); 
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
     
     public void run() {
      ImageView dog;
            dog.setImageResource(R.drawable.dog1);
        } 
    }, 2000);
   
   }   
  });

Comment: I do like above, but there is an error message in the line "dog.setImageResource(R.drawable.dog1);" stating: The local variable dog may not have been initialized

Comment: solved thid by replacing 'ImageView dog;' with 'ImageView dog = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.dog);'

Comment: dog.setImageDrawable(R.drawable.dog1);    use this.

Answer (score 0):

To change the imageView content you use :

```
yourImageView.setImageDrawableResouce(R.drawable.imgTemp);
```

To count 1 second, you can use

```
final ScheduledExecutorService exec = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

exec.schedule(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run(){
       setYourImageView();//return the image to the original one
    }
}, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

To do it in the UI thread you can use

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {

                            yourImageView.setImageDrawableResouce(R.drawable.imgTemp);
                           }

                        }
                    });
```